# How to set automatic referesh for Text view in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My application is like to deliver the House hold products in door step.After,customer order the products give a order status to the customer like pending,progress,packed etc.It will fetch from server.When the order status change by the manager in PC.how to get a status automatically in order status page in my app.any one know share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use service that check whether status is update or not.  If update then change status on textview.  But it is not a good practice.  So, I think that you have to use Push Notification for status update.

Comment: @klWe have use runnable thread or some thing like tat gud or not

Comment: Yes, this is one of the way.  But it reduce your application performance.  Because it is send request every time on server.

Comment: when go to next activity,we have to destroy tat runnable activity.Its good idea or bad.

Comment: suppose, when are you non runnable thread activity and user put this application in background.  Then what will happen ?.  You runnable thread is not working.